# Printing out how many of each char from alphabet does file have. - C

Tags: c, file, char

Hello fellow programmers. I have huge problem figuring out this program, been sitting on it for hours. Here is what I need. Program that is calculating chars for each line in file. As far as I got I currently have program calculating and printing lines and also printing A-Z chars. Also there is no difference between for example t & T so program count both as T. Here is what I coded yet.

input: Hi its me

output: H - 1, I - 2, T - 1,  S - 1, M - 1, E - 1

But it will also print 0 for chars that are not present. For example A - 0 etc.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fr;
    char *fname, a='A',b;
    int line = 1, lines=1,i=0,counter=0,z=0;

    //Scans file name & open it

    scanf("%s",fname);
    fr = fopen(fname,"r");

    //print out first line

    printf("  ");
    for (;a<='Z';a++) {
        printf(" %c",a);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //calculate how many lines file has

    while (fscanf(fr,"%c",&b) != EOF) {
        if (b == '\n') {
            lines++;
        }
    }

    //cycle for printing lines

    for (;line<=lines;) {
        printf("%d  ",line);

        //check till end of file

        while ((fscanf(fr,"%c",&b) != EOF)) {
            printf("%c ",a);
            //check a-z
            for (a='A';a<='Z';a++) {
                if (b == a || a+32 == b) {
                    counter++;
                }
                else if (b == '\n') {
                    line++; printf("\n");
                }

            }
            printf("%d ",counter);
            counter=0;
        }
    }
    fclose(fr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It prints that because you ask it to. Move those print statements into an `if` that tests `counter`.

Comment: But then I will receieve for example if A will be in file twice A - 1 1 and not A - 2

Comment: Because you are printing your results immediately. Now if there were only some way to store them into some kind of list ...

Comment: I did try it with arrays, it was pain because I cannot figure out how to tell it that it is new line so it should stop and printf results for current line and then begin to count the other line

Comment: You forgot to rewind the file.

Comment: You are currently programming yourself into a deep hole. There is currently no way to point at a flaw in your program, since the whole direction you are going is flawed. Implement it using an array, and repost the question if you can't get it to work. We can't show you how you are using the array wrong, unless there is an array in there somewhere

Comment: @WeatherVane I do not know what does that mean, can you explain to me please?

Comment: @HAL9000 will do mate, soon enought

Comment: The library function `rewind` — in the second section you are already at `EOF`.

Comment: Okay, still not working tho, but thanks for idea, never knew that this is also happening.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",fname);` when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 2) when using the input format specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  -1 because those input format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: regarding array usage:  `int counts[ 256 ];  at top of reading each line: `memset( counts, 0, sizeof( counts ) );`  for each character in the line: `counts[ line[i] ]++;`   after processing the whole line: `for( int i=0; i<256; i++) { if( counts[i] ) printf( "%c - %i\n" , (char)i, counts[ i  ] ); }`

Comment: Tip - Don't use `printf ("%c", a);` to print a single character, that is what `putchar (a);` is for. A good compiler should optimize it for your, but using the correct tool for the job to begin with -- shows you know what your are doing `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggest:

to eliminate any 'magic' numbers:

```
#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 100
#define MAX_LINE_LEN     1024
#define MAX_CHARACTERS   256
```

replace:

```
char *fname, a='A',b;
```

with:

```
char fname[ MAX_FILENAME_LEN ];
```

otherwise, trying to read the file name into some random memory (a good way to cause a seg fault event and it is undefined behavior)

replace:

```
printf("  ");
for (;a<='Z';a++) {
    printf(" %c",a);
}
printf("\n");
```

with:

```
char line[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];
fgets( line, sizeof line, fr );
printf( "%s", line );
```

replace this:

```
scanf("%s",fname);
fr = fopen(fname,"r");
```

with:

```
if( scanf("%99s",fname) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to input file name"
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
// implied else, scanf successful

fr = fopen(fname,"r");
if( !fr )
{
    perror( "fopen failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
// implied else, fopen successful
```

replace

```
    while (fscanf(fr,"%c",&b) != EOF) {
    if (b == '\n') {
        lines++;
    }
}
```

with:

```
int lines = 1;
while( fgets( line, sizeof line, fr ) )
{
    lines++;
}
rewind( fr );
```

replace:

```
        while ((fscanf(fr,"%c",&b) != EOF)) {
        printf("%c ",a);
        //check a-z
        for (a='A';a<='Z';a++) {
            if (b == a || a+32 == b) {
                counter++;
            }
            else if (b == '\n') {
                line++; printf("\n");
            }

        }
        printf("%d ",counter);
        counter=0;
    }
```

with:

```
int counts[ MAX_CHARACTERS ];
...
// use `While()` loop with `fgets()` to read data into `line[]`
...
memset( counts, '\0', sizeof( counts ) ); 

for( int i=0; line[i]; i++ )
{
    counts[ line[i] ]++; 
}

for( int i=0; i<MAX_CHARACTERS; i++) 
{ 
    if( counts[i] ) 
    {
        printf( "%c - %i\n" , (char)i, counts[ i ] ); 
    } 
}
```

You may want to 'tweak' the above to not output punctuation, newlines, etc.

You may want to 'tweak' the above to count both upper and lower case alpha characters as the same.  An easy way to do that is to

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

and then for each char selected from the 'line[]' array:

```
line[i] = tolower( line[i] );
```

Note:  `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: Any reason in particular you didn't want to combine the operations all under a single `while( fgets( line, sizeof line, fr )` loop and avoid the multiple reads from the file and need to `rewind()`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I followed the code logic of the OP,  Otherwise, I could easily have written my answer as a single loop, However, the OPs posted code outputs the number of lines in the input file, before processing any of the lines in the input file,  So the count of the number of lines in the input file (following the OPs code logic) needed to be calculated first, then step back to the beginning of the file and process each line

Comment: I figured as much. Your suggestions were good, but the explanation was a bit limited. (replace... with...) Sometimes giving the OP a bit of the (why...) and overview of how to tidy things up isn't such a bad idea. Here if they were using a short example file, it really doesn't matter, but if the file was huge, then there would be a great deal of efficiency to be gained in reading once.